# the long ignorance of Italy for the warnings from China

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does the phrase "the long ignorance of Italy for the warnings from China" mean "ignoring Italy for long time because of the warnings from China" (That is, the pandemic situations in China drew all attention to the country, so Italy was ignored - yet actually, in the opinion of this top virologist of Germany, Italy was the origin of the novel virus)?

> The expert also noted that for a global pandemic, the beginning shot was fired in northern Italy. The virologist stated that **the long ignorance of Italy for the warnings from China** and the lack of countermeasures are to be blamed, otherwise, the original virus can have been got under control.

> Source: International Business Times  published on November 28, 2020
> [COVID-19: Top German Virologist Says New Coronavirus Not From Wuhan](https://www.ibtimes.sg/covid-19-top-german-virologist-says-new-coronavirus-not-wuhan-53730)

Comment: As an Italian who has a relative living in Bergamo, I contest the German virologist conclusions as stated in the article. Nobody in the world knew anything about this novel virus. Back in February, Italian doctors were told to test for the virus only if anyone had recently visited China.  The fact of the matter, many of the seriously ill patients had never had any direct or indirect contact with China, so their symptoms were misdiagnosed.

Comment: The scientist claims that the deadly variant is to be blamed on its mutation in Italy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the long ignorance of Italy for the warnings from China

This is not a good expression in English, and it's ambiguous. It probably means that the world ignored Italy because they were paying attention to China, as you suggest, or it could mean that Italy was ignorant because they ignored warnings from China. The word "ignorance" in English doesn't mean the same as "the ignoring", so it's a bad word choice.

Similarly, the phrase
*the original virus can have been got under control.*
is not at all idiomatic. A simpler expression in English is
*the original virus could have been got under control*
or just
*the original virus could have been controlled.*